# UIActivityIndicatorView does't show after clicking UITableview row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview, viewdidload

Indicator doest show after click, it first load the next page and then show up for few mili seconds. i want it to stay there from row click till next screen load completely.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
activityIndicator.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"6"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Try putting the code of the indicator on the main thread

Comment: @Jasper like this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code so you put the `UIActivityIndicatorView` code on the main thread.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
        activityIndicator.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
        [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    });


    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"6"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: yes, i was trying this so long... this is not working... not even show for few mili seconds now

Comment: That is probably because, you don't have an activity indicator in your view controller where you are transitioning to. Your activity indicator have started animating in your first view controller where you have the tableview but then you present the second view controller where you don't have any activity indicator. As the transition is very fast, you are not seeing the activity indicator at all.

Comment: @natasha nope my transition is not fast, it's taking almost 20 secs to run next page as next page's viewdidload has heavy job to do... that's why i was showing indicator... but it's not working... it shows in the end when transition happen after 20 sec...

Comment: Why don't you add the `UIActivityIndicatorView` already on your `UIView` when you setup your view. Then only animate/show it when you need it.

Comment: If that is the case then you need to have two activity indicators- one on the first view controller and the other in the second, because as soon as you start presenting the second view controller, you loose you activity indicator in the first page.

Comment: Adding it to UIWindow (like MBProgressHUD does) would be a solution then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this but you still won't see any activity indicator in the second view controller as you don't have one in the second view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
    activityIndicator.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;

    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    });

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"6"];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        }];
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not show the `UIActivityIndicator` on the next page until it loads?

Start it in `viewWillappear` or `viewDidLoad` on the next screen, end it when its finished loading

Comment: actually my screen is taking time to go next VC, and i have to show indicator in first page...

Answer (score 0):

You start `UIActivityIndicator` and then move to next View Controller. Because of quick transition, you can see the indicator for only a while. You can add the activity indicator on your other View Controller, and show it as long as you want.